# If $g$ is a polynomial and real numbers $a<c<b$ are three roots of $g$, then $g''-g$ has a root in $[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

There is a sub-question before this, asking me to prove that $g'+g$ has a root in $[a,b]$ (call this proposition 1), which I did.

My thought is to let $f=g'+g$ and $h=f'-f$ so that $h=g''-g$. Then by proposition 1, $f$ has a root in $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$. If $r_1\in [a,c)$ and $r_2\in (c, b]$ are two roots of $f$, then I would be able to show that $h$ has a root in $[r_1, r_2]$ by a technique similar to the one used to prove proposition 1.

But what if $f$ has only one root, namely $c$, in $[a,b]$? Is this possible? I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show that $f= g'+g$ has a root in each of the *open* intervals $(a, c)$ and $(c, b)$, by applying Rolle's theorem to $e^x g(x)$.

That gives you two *distinct* roots $r_1$ and $r_2$ of $f$, and it follows that $f' = g''-g$ has a root in the open interval $(r_1, r_2)$.

Note that $g$ need not be a polynomial, it suffices that $g$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$.